# How to traverse JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, frontend, traversal

I have this script:

```
<script>
    function postForm() {
        $.post("rest/login", $("#myform").serialize()).done(function(data) {

            if(data.status === "OK"){
                window.location.replace("coursesform.jsp");
                alert(data);
            }
            else alert (data.status);

                //alert("Invalid credentials. Please use the same username and password you'd use for a SoCS machine.");
        });
    }
</script>
```

I changed what the login API brings back from simply outputting this:

```
{"status":"OK"}
```

into outputting the user id as well:

```
{"status":"{au:true, id:testtutor}"}
```

How can I extract "true" and "testtutor"?

I tried this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(status.data);
```

So I can do `obj.au` however I receive this:

however, I receive this in the browser:

```
VM701:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
```

Comment: `{"status":"{au:true, id:testtutor}"}` is odd. It's JSON notation for an object with a single property, `status`, whose value is a string. The more normal version of that would be `{"status":{"au":true, "id":"testtutor"}}`, which is an object with a property, `status`, whose value is an object with two properties, `au` and `id`, whose values are `true` and `"testtutor"`, respectively. So the first step to working with these values would be to output them in an easy-to-use format.

Comment: Shouldn't `status.data` be `data.status`?

Comment: The problem seems to be in the controller, it's not generating correct JSON. I suspect you're trying to create the JSON by hand, and doing it wrong, instead of using a library function.

Comment: Barmar is right, you should be creating an object then using the languages toJSON function, something like `({status: "OK", id: "testtutor"}).toJSON()` (don't know what your backend language is)

Answer (score 0):

```
{"status":"{au:true, id:testtutor}"}
```

Remove " around {au:true, id:testtutor},
to make it

```
{"status":{au:true, id:"testtutor"}}
```

Then you will be able to get au by status.au and id by status.id

You are getting an Error because `"{au:true, id:testtutor}"` is not a valid JSON it needs to be `{"au":true, "id":"testtutor"}` but You can't do this because you already have " around it.

Answer (score 0):

Your API isn't returning valid JSON, or at least not in the way you're expecting. Your keys should be strings in JSON, so you should be returning something like:

```
{
  "status": {
    "au": true,
    "id": "testtutor"
  }
}
```

...which `JSON.parse()` will be able to parse.